# StaticFrame RuntimeError: Store label {label} is not a string; provide a label_encoder to StoreConfig

Tags: python, static-frame

I am trying to export a yarn to_zip_npz, but I am getting this runtime error. How exactly do I fix this? For instance here is a toy example that kindly follows my use case. How would I make this example work?

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import static_frame as sf

path = Path(f'datasets')
npz_file = path / 'npz_yarn_test.zip'

frame_data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
frames = []
for i in range(1,4):
    frame = sf.Frame(frame_data, columns=('first', 'second', 'third'), name = f'frame_{i}')
    frames.append(frame)

buses = []
for i in range(1,4):
    bus = sf.Bus.from_frames(frames, name = f'bus_{i}')
    buses.append(bus)

sf.Yarn.from_buses(buses, retain_labels=True).to_zip_npz(npz_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I got the answer from a response on the StaticFrame GitHub.

"The issue here is that the Yarn you have created has an IndexHierarchy since you set retain_labels=True:

```
>>> yn

<Yarn>
<IndexHierarchy>
bus_1            frame_1 Frame
bus_1            frame_2 Frame
bus_1            frame_3 Frame
bus_2            frame_1 Frame
bus_2            frame_2 Frame
bus_2            frame_3 Frame
bus_3            frame_1 Frame
bus_3            frame_2 Frame
bus_3            frame_3 Frame
<<U5>            <<U7>   <object>
```

When we go to write to an NPZ, we use the Yarn labels to name the components in the file store, and those components must be strings. The labels given from an IndexHierarchy, however, are tuples. We can encode and decode those tuples using a StoreConfig, providing a function to encode (going to a string) and decode (going from string back to the label). Thus, to round-trip this Yarn to and from a ZIP NPZ, we can do the following:

```
>>> yn.to_zip_npz('/tmp/npz.zip', config=sf.StoreConfig(label_encoder=str))

>>> import ast
>>> sf.Bus.from_zip_npz('/tmp/npz.zip', config=sf.StoreConfig(label_decoder=ast.literal_eval), 
index_constructor=sf.IndexHierarchy.from_labels)

<Bus>
<IndexHierarchy>
bus_1            frame_1 <FrameDeferred>
bus_1            frame_2 <FrameDeferred>
bus_1            frame_3 <FrameDeferred>
bus_2            frame_1 <FrameDeferred>
bus_2            frame_2 <FrameDeferred>
bus_2            frame_3 <FrameDeferred>
bus_3            frame_1 <FrameDeferred>
bus_3            frame_2 <FrameDeferred>
bus_3            frame_3 <FrameDeferred>
<<U5>            <<U7>   <object>
```

Note that while the label_decoder will give us back tuples, we still need to provide an index_constructor to create an IndexHierachy."